# android activity result null pointer exception

Tags: android, camera, onactivityresult

I'm creating an android app that takes several pictures are samples. I have the following in the onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sampling);

    initLocalVariables();
}

private void initLocalVariables() {
    this.sampleView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sampleView);
    this.startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startSamplingButton);

    this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 4000, 1, this);
    this.currentLocation = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    this.paintBrush = new Paint();
    this.paintBrush.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    this.companyId = 0;
    this.fieldId = 0;
    this.plantSetId = 0;
    this.standardRadius = 10f;
    this.colorSelected = null;
    this.sampleView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    this.isSelectingPoint = false;

    this.configureSample();

}
```

The initLocalVariables method initialize the local variables and objects and calls the following method.

```
private void configureSample() {
    if (this.sampleList == null) {
        this.sampleList = new ArrayList<Muestra>();
    }

    if (this.sampleList.size() == 0) {
        this.currentSample = new Muestra();
        this.currentSample.setIdMuestra(1);
        this.currentSample.setIdEmpresa(this.companyId);
        this.currentSample.setIdCampo(this.fieldId);
        this.currentSample.setIdPanyo(this.plantSetId);
    } else {
        this.currentSample = this.currentSample.obtenerSiguienteMuestra();

        if (this.currentLocation != null) {
            this.currentSample.setUbicacion(new GeoLocation(this.currentLocation.getLatitude(), this.currentLocation.getLongitude(), this.currentLocation.getAltitude(),
                    this.currentLocation.getAccuracy()));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the currentSample is not null. I ask te system to take the picture like this.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        this.currentPicture = this.currentSample.obtenerSiguienteImagenMuestra(directorioAlmacenamiento);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.currentPicture.obtieneUriDesdeArchivo());
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

I take the picture and I ask to save in the filesystem. The picture is saved but when finishing saving the application throws the following exception.

**12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.agrobotica.agroberries/com.agrobotica.agroberries.SamplingActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.agrobotica.agroberries/com.agrobotica.agroberries.SamplingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2919)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2948)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.agrobotica.agroberries/com.agrobotica.agroberries.SamplingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3500)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    ... 12 more
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at com.agrobotica.agroberries.SamplingActivity.onActivityResult(SamplingActivity.java:231)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3496)
12-17 21:47:23.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15493):    ... 13 more**

I don't get to the onActivityResult while debugging. This my onActivityResult.

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (this.currentLocation == null) {
            this.currentLocation = this.locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }

        if (this.currentLocation != null) {
            this.currentSample.setUbicacion(new GeoLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), currentLocation.getAltitude(), currentLocation
                    .getAccuracy()));
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = currentPicture.convertToAndroidBitmap();
        this.imageCanvas = new Canvas();
        this.imageCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
        this.sampleView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

To start the sampling process I do the following.

```
public void onClickStartSampling(View v) {
    this.startButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    this.sampleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Checking the developing options in the phone I found out that it was checked the "No keeping activities" at the end of the option list. This was closing the activity after starting the camera activity so it the activity was null when it returned from saving the picture.